# Impact of new added categories to a Business View on Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

I am working on a crystal report 2016 and the report is populating some values from a 'Business view'.
I don't have access to the business view.

Our company has to add some new categories to a table used by that busniess view.

My question is, when the new category will be added to the table, will the report automatically incorporate that new categories and display on the report?

And if the report is run through a schedule, do I need to create a new schedule for the report?

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: Just to make it clear, the new categories added are not the new columns but just the new values to the existing column. DO I need to create a new schedule and how to show the added categories on the report. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you open the crystal report in the designer it will check the schema saved in the report against the schema in the database.  If it detects a difference, it will update the schema on the report and pump a notification pop-up to the user for each table or view that is updated in the schema.

However, this does not add the new fields to the report automatically.  It only updates the schema.  You will need to edit the report and manually add the new database fields to the report.  Once the schema is updated you should be find the new fields listed in the Field Explorer so you can drop them where they are needed on the report.

If you only added new values to the database and did not add new columns, then the schema should be the same and would not require an update.  The new data should appear on the report as long as there are no formulas causing sections of the report to be suppressed and there is no selection criteria that might filter the new data.  You shouldn't need a new schedule either, unless there are runtime parameters that need to be changed.